# Find the coefficients $a$ and $b$ of a polynomial which has a double zero $x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Find the coefficients $a$ and $b$ of the polynomial $ax^4+bx^2+1$, if it has a double zero at $x=1$.

How do I begin this because I am out of ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$(ax^4+bx^2+1)_{x=1}=0$$ and
$$(ax^4+bx^2+1)'_{x=1}=0$$ and solve the following system:
$$a+b+1=0$$ and $$4a+2b=0$$

Comment: Can you explain to me how do we get into this system of equations?

Comment: I just saw that, thanks, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Since the polynomial is even, if $x=1$ is a double root, $x=-1$ must also be a double root. Therefore

$$ ax^4 + bx^2 + 1 = (x-1)^2(x+1)^2 $$

Expanding the RHS gives $a = 1, b = -2$

Answer (score 1):

**Shortcut**:

Notice that $$(x_1-1)^2=x_1^2-2x_1+1$$ so if you let $x_1=x^2$ then you get $$(x^2-1)^2=\color{red}{(x-1)^2}(x+1)^2=x^4-2x^2+1$$ thus $$(a,b)=(1,-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* A polynomial $p(x)$ has a double zero at $x=1$ iff $p(1)=0$ and $p'(1)=0$.